# How to Verifying bot authenticity other than checking for varification token in Hangouts chat Bot?

Tags: google-hangouts

I integrated hangouts chat BOT with my java webhook. I am getting messages properly from DM also, but my question is how can I validate the incoming message identity other than comparing verification token that I am getting in every Event object and comparing it with verification token I have in Bot creation page in Google developer console?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a service account here -> https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Enable Chat API here -> https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/
3. Download the service key
4. You can find code on Google Chat documentation for authenticating a service account. Here is an example in Python

   ```
   scopes= 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot' 
   credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('<service_key_name>.json', scopes)
   http2 = Http()
   credentials.authorize(http2)
   service = build('chat', 'v1', http=http2)
   <use service here for REST API>
   ```

   example:

   ```
   resp = service.spaces().messages().create( parent = spaceName, body = chatBody).execute()
   ```